# ikvm on wp7, wp7 mango, or silverlight 4+?

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, ikvm

Is it possible to run [ikvm](http://www.ikvm.net/) in "dynamic mode" on wp7? I know wp7 versions prior to 7.5 (mango) have limitations such as lack of reflection.emit that might throw a wrench in ikvm's implementation, however some of those limitations are gone in mango (including the addition of reflection.emit), so I'm wondering if someone's already tried using ikvm on wp7, wp7 mango, or even on Silverlight 4. If so, how was your experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, IKVM does not run on WP7 or with Silverlight currently.